# Shapiro-Wilk test for normality gives $W= 0.7$ and P value = 1.659e-10. How do I interpret P: Is it greater than 0.05? Need help. Thanks

Tags: statistical-significance

I have done a Shapiro-Wilk normality test and my results are
$W= 0.79428$, $p$-value$= 1.659e^{-10}$. Is the $p$-value greater than or less than $0.05$?

Answer (score 7):

**Notation for values very near zero,** in computer printouts `1.659e-10` means 'almost' $0.$
That's shorthand for $1.659 \times 10^{-10},$ so you move the
decimal point 10 places to the *left* to get the intended result.
Here are sample computations in R to illustrate:

```
1/5
[1] 0.2
1/500
[1] 0.002
1/500000
[1] 2e-06
1 + 1/500000
[1] 1.000002
```

For the example in your question, some statistical software would
give you simply `< 0.005`, to show a very small P-value, very much
below 5%, so that you would reject at the 5% level, 1% level, 0.1%
level, etc. To be specific, the Shapiro-Wilk test has found the
data that prompted your question to be very noticeably far from normal.

---

That's the end of the minimal answer to your question about
the notation for values very near $0.$ But because it seems
you're just getting started with methods of assessing normality
I will show you a few additional things that may be of interest.

Sometimes, especially for small samples, it is better to judge
by eye from a normal probability plot (sometimes called 'normal
quantile plot' of 'normal QQ-plot').

**Example: Small non-normal sample.** For example, consider a sample of size $n=10$ from an exponential distribution. The Shapiro-Wilk test rejects normality but may seem
sort of "borderline" with a P-value not much below 5%. [In R, the `$`-notation lets you look just at the P-value instead of several lines of output.]

```
set.seed(411)
x1 = rexp(10, .01)
shapiro.test(x1)$p.val
[1] 0.03610927
```

But in a normal probability plot, truly normal data should give points
reasonably near a straight line, which his sample does not.

```
qqnorm(x1);  qqline(x1, col="green", lwd=2)
```

[image]

**Example: Large non-normal sample.** If you have a large sample from an exponential population, then the S-W test leaves little doubt.

```
x2 = rexp(1000, .01)
shapiro.test(x2)$p.val
[1] 1.853935e-31        # Far below 5%
```

**Example: Large normal sample.** For a large normal sample, the S-W test will almost always give a P-value above 5%. (But don't fall into the trap of saying a result
with a P-value around .9 is "more normal" than one around .4; P-values are not intended to be used in that way.)

```
x3 = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
shapiro.test(x3)$p.val
[1] 0.9314421
```

A normal probability plot of such a large normal sample should show points very nearly along a straight line (but you should excuse a few
'wobbles' in the 'tails' where data are sparse).

```
qqnorm(x3);  qqline(x3, col="green", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Interpret P-values above 5% with care.* Here is a demonstration showing P-values of Shapiro-Wilk
tests for 100,000 truly normal datasets of size 100.
The P-values are nearly uniformly scattered between $0$ and $1.$
Because of the variability of the data and the nature of the
test, it is best not to 'grade' the normality of a sample
based just on its P-value if it 'passes' a S-W test.

```
set.seed(2021)
pv =replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rnorm(100,50,7))$p.val)
summary(pv)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000081 0.2527493 0.5015454 0.4999672 0.7460409 0.9999346 

hdr = "Histogram of S-W P-values from 100,000 Normal Samples"
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, -.1, 1.1, col="orange", lwd=2, n=10001)
```

[image]

*Note:* Even though a truly normal sample can occasionally
give a S-W P-value below 5% (hence being 'rejected' as not normal), that kind of occasional mistake is inevitable in hypothesis
testing. It's what we mean by a "5% significance level".
(The far left-hand bar in the histogram above corresponds to
these "Type I Errors."

"Type II Errors" occur when a
truly non-normal sample gets a P-value above 5%. Much of the theory of hypothesis testing centers on strategies to minimize both kinds of error.)